# How can I get createAt object?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongoose

I am building a simple website using node js now.
However, during the creation, an object in the document was not output.
The code below is a simple schema.

```
// model/Post.js

const PostSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    body: String,
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    updatedAt: Date
});
```

```
// routes/posts.js

const express = require('express');
const app = express.Router();
const Post = require('../models/Post');

router.get('/', function(req, res){
    const query = Post.find({});
    query.select('-createdAt');
    query.exec(function(err, posts){
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        res.render('posts/index', { posts: posts });
    });
});
```

I want to load createdAt in postSchema and print it in html, what should I do?
Below is a part of the html code.

```
<!-- views/posts/index.ejs -->

<% posts.forEach(post => { %>
<tr>
  <td>
    <a class="nav-link" href="/posts"><div class="ellipsis"><%= post.title %></div></a>
  </td>
  <td><%= post.createdAt %></td> <!-- I want to print createdAt -->
</tr>
<% }) %>
```

I'm using packages express, ejs, mongoose

How can I print the createdAt object?

Answer (score 1):

remove query.select('-createdAt') in your code, basically it will remove createdAt in the result, and you will get all other attributes from schema.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res){
    const query = Post.find({});
    query.exec(function(err, posts){
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        res.render('posts/index', { posts: posts });
    });
});
```